# How to create a cocoapod with .swift?

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I know how to work with cocoapods in a new swift project?
**But how can i create my own cocoapod using swift?**

**pod lib lint** produces this error:

```
- NOTE  | [xcodebuild]  warning: no rule to process file '/Pod/Classes/SomeClass.swift' of type text for architecture armv7
```

**Edit:**
Just found this swift branch:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/tree/swift

Answer (score 3):

Cocoapods now supports swift : [Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/)

Answer (score 1):

Although Swift is officially supported, there are [no official templates available for Swift](https://github.com/CocoaPods/pod-template/issues/88) and documentation is still slim. Here's a [step-by-step tutorial](http://basememara.com/how-to-create-a-cocoapod-with-swift/) for creating CocoaPods in Swift that may help though.

Essentially the steps are:

1. Create a git repo
2. Create your Xcode workspace
3. Add an iOS/OSX example project
4. Add Swift framework and make it as a dependency to your example project
5. Create your pod spec file, here's an example for a Swift pod:

   ```
   Pod::Spec.new do |s|

       s.name         = "MySwiftPod"
       s.version      = "0.1"
       s.summary      = "This is my amazing Swift CocoaPod!"

       s.description  = <<-DESC
                        This is my long description here... yada, yada.
                        DESC

       s.homepage     = "http://basememara.com/how-to-create-a-cocoapod-with-swift/"
       s.screenshots  = "www.example.com/screenshots_1.gif", "www.example.com/screenshots_2.gif"
       s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
       s.author             = { "Basem Emara" => "some@example.com" }
       s.social_media_url   = "https://twitter.com/basememara"
       s.platform     = :ios, "8.0"
       s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/basememara/cocoapods-swift-sample.git", :tag => s.version }
       s.source_files  = "MySwiftPod/MySwiftPod/*.swift"

   end
   ```

Comment: I posted this answer in another SO thread. Here it is for reference in case there is progress over there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376297/create-cocoapod-for-swift-framework/30103652

Comment: Hey I read your step-by-step guide, I found it very helpful - I was able to create a prototype pod I can install via the 'pod install' command. I'm having trouble, though, figuring out how to make a pod that depends on another pod. For instance, the library I'd like to create uses SnapKit. I know you have to list dependencies in the podspec file, but how does one actually go about incorporating pre-existing cocoapods into the project structure you laid out in your tutorial?