# Create Cocoapod for swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am planning to make Cocoapod for my framework written in Swift which is placed on github [here](https://github.com/abdullah-chhatra/iDate). I went through the Cocoapod documentation but I am not able to wrap my head around it.

Could anyone please explain how to achieve it or point to any tutorial that will explain it.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple. I found this [video tutorial](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/28-creating-a-cocoapod) incredibly helpful when I started. It's for Objective-C, but should pretty much be the same for Swift.

Also, the video is from a few years back, so when it tells you to 'do a pull request to the Cocoapods specs repo' just ignore it.
Since that video came out, Cocoapods has stopped accepting pull requests to their specs repo. Now you need to run a command called `trunk` which essentially lets Cocoapods add the spec automatically. You can read more about it [here](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-Trunk/)

You also may find it helpful to check out some examples of Swift pod specs like [this](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift/blob/master/SCLAlertView.podspec)